# Phpmyadmin will not save data from perfectly good PHP and HTML code

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

Phpmyadmin (xampp for Windows) will not save data from perfectly good PHP and HTML code:

```
<html>
    <?php
        $news = $_POST['news'];
        $con = mysql_connect['127.0.0.1','root',''];
        mysql_select_db($con, 'chidon')
        $select="INSERT INTO `news`(`news`) VALUES ([$news]";
        mysql_query($con, $select);
    ?>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action='webpage.html' method="POST">
        <div>
        <h4>News:</h4><input type="text" name="news">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">
    </body>
</html>
```

So please help me because it's very frustrating...
Thanks.

Comment: "perfectly good" except for the glaring syntax errors, SQL injection vulnerability, complete lack of error handling, use of deprecated functions, and *incorrect* use of those functions...

Comment: `action='webpage.html'` that's where the problem starts, then you have more errors, too many actually.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are far too many syntax errors made.

Comment: Ok, I'll stop editing that first comment.  Every time I look back at this "perfectly good code" more errors become evident.  Start with *any* introductory tutorial on PHP and MySQL.  And drop the assumption that everything you do is perfect.

Comment: I'm tempted to rewrite the title to "Code abundant in syntax errors does not store to database for some reason. No error_reporting enabled." to make it at least searchable for future users.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely nothing about this is "perfectly good".

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated, you need to use PDO or MySQLi.

```
$con = mysql_connect['127.0.0.1','root',''];
```

Should be (albeit not a `mysql_*` function):

```
$con = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1','root','');
```

This line:

```
mysql_select_db($con, 'chidon')
```

Should have a semicolon at the end:

```
mysql_select_db($con, 'chidon');
```

This line:

```
$select="INSERT INTO `news`(`news`) VALUES ([$news]";
```

Should be:

```
$select="INSERT INTO `news`(`news`) VALUES ('$news')";
```

...and should use prepared statements (available in MySQLi and PDO libraries).

Finally:

```
<form action='webpage.html' method="POST">
```

Doesn't make any sense, how are you expecting to use the data if you're posting to a HTML file? You probably mean `webpage.php`, and might need to change your file extension to match this too.

Also, this has nothing to do with PHPMyAdmin, PHPMyAdmin is just a tool used to access and manipulate a MySQL database, it's not the actual database itself.

Comment: That should also have `mysql_real_escape_string` if this code is stuck in the 1990s.

Comment: Check `mysql_select_db()` again.

Comment: My answer will certainly not solve all your problems; only the ones presented in this post. I'm willing to bet any money you've got many more if I managed to find all these ones in only 5 lines of code.